# show woocommerce nav filter widget on custom query product archive page template

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have custom template in my woocommerce store which shows products archive with custom query. I set up woocommerce default layer nav filter widget to sidebar but it does'nt appears on that page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

woocommerce default layer nav filter widget works only on shop page, not custom template..